# Creepage between Phase/Neutral and Earth (PCB Design)

Tags: ac

The smallest distance between line and neutral on my PCB is 4mm, which ought to be enough for 240V mains. I had a copper pour connected to earth around every trace with a clearance of 1mm. Someone told me I should get rid of it.

I thought creepage could only occur between phase and neutral, but perhaps it applies also to earth? What should I do?

Comment: Get rid of it..

Comment: Though experiment: (1) What is the voltage on the neutral line. (2) What is the voltage on the earth line? (3) How would creepage differ between the two? (4) What would happen if L and N are switched?

Comment: Thanks! I have gotten rid of it and added a track to connect my plated mounting hole (earth point) to my EMI filter. Here is a picture of how the tracks are routed: https://ibb.co/GvRwcX0 Could someone have a quick look and tell me if there are any risks now? I have DC on this board to control the relay (two small red tracks). AC shouldn't be able to get to it, right?

Comment: Neutral and Earth are effectively the same thing.   They're literally tied together at your homes breaker box.   So for your purpose, yes you should have adequate creepage from both.

Comment: Thank you all for your help. I am definitely a newbie when it comes to AC, and now I understand it better. With the earth plane gone, the AC side of the board is at least safe now. I have created another thread about optimal clearance, creepage and other measures (?) to protect DC from mains AC here: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/494264/protect-dc-circuit-from-ac