# Protect DC circuit from AC

Tags: ac, dc, circuit-protection

First and foremost, I would like to point out that I am a beginner in electronics.

I have designed a board that is meant to be connected to 240V AC. However, there is a relay on it that has a 12V DC coil. This means that I have to physically bring DC over to this board and I have selected a Molex KK254 two pin connector for this purpose. It sits pretty close to the relay and there is enough enough clearance on my PCB (at least 4mm pretty much everywhere) but I am still worried about AC finding its way to it. The  DC supply is also nearby and powers delicate electronics.

Here is the schematic (it's pretty straightforward. Also, the "AC Phase Output" is fused later down the line):

[image: AC board schematic]

And here is the current PCB layout (NB: there are no copper filled zones/pours, picture updated 20/4/20):

[image: PCB layout]

As you can tell, I have already made a T cut to separate DC from AC at the relay to make the creepage distance larger.

**The smallest distance (clearance) between AC and DC is 9-10mm (.35 inch). Is this enough to protect the DC supply or should I add more components (i.e. a Zener Diode?)?**

Thanks in advance for your suggestions.

Comment: It depends on the protection over the conductors and your target environment.

Comment: The board will be FR-4 with an RoHS compliant HASL finish. It will be screwed to the metal casing using spacers at the earth points and enclosed inside it (the user won't have access to the dangerous voltages).

Comment: What environment will the device be used in?

Comment: It's meant to be placed between the mains input of a computer (right after the C14 receptacle) and an ATX PSU (after the original EMI filter, in effect bypassing it, hence the need of a new one on the board in question). The goal being to replace the old PSU components with modern ATX guts. There's also a second PCB (that handles DC from the ATX PSU and where the +12VDC will come from) but this one's fine and isn't as challenging. In a way, this 'AC Board' is going to work like an extension cord.